# About the size of the orbitals $s$, $p$, $d$, etc, in $H$ atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, hydrogen, orbitals

Can we define a size for the H atom orbitals which are not spherically symmetric, e.g. $p, d$ etc? For example, is it meaningful to say that the $(n+1)p$ orbital is larger in its extent than $np$ orbital ($n$ is the principal quantum number)?

Comment: The orbitals are spherically symmetric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#/media/File%3ARotating_spherical_harmonics.gif

Comment: Only s orbitals are spherically symmetric.

Comment: Why should make less sense to speak about the size of p,d,,f orbitals than about the size of s orbitals?

Comment: @Poutnik as you said, only s orbitals are spherically symmetric. so what do you mean by size?

Comment: @mithusenguota123 It depends what we mean by orbital 1/particular solution of the wave equation 2/ quantum state of electron 3/ geometrical shape described by the surface of the same arbitrary value of $\Psi \cdot \bar \Psi$. But the size of the 3/ can be taken either as the average radius as in one of the answers, either as the maximal radius with the given orbital surface probability limit.

Comment: @safesphere: The animation you linked to is just depicting the spherical harmonics, not the hydrogen wavefunctions.

Comment: @BenCrowell I don’t think that that explains @safesphere’s misunderstanding, because the radial factor *is*, almost by definition, radially symmetric. So *all* of the asymmetry comes from the spherical harmonics. It is evident in the animation from the fact that the color over the sphere is not uniform, except for the first one. (And it is confusing that the shading makes even that one look asymmetric.)

Comment: @G.Smith My understanding is fine, thank you. The probability density is uneven within the sphere, but it is a sphere. Is it not?

Comment: @safesphere No, you seem quite confused. Of course it is a sphere, because spherical harmonics are functions only of $\theta$ and $\phi$, which define a direction. But their *value* in one direction is not the same as their value in another direction. The spherical harmonics live *on* the sphere, not *within* the sphere.

Comment: @safesphere To understand the H orbitals, look at these plots: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Hydrogen-atomic-orbitals-represented-as-probability-density-plots-The-darker-the_fig1_228078714 All of that asymmetry in 3D is coming from the angular asymmetry of the spherical harmonics.

Comment: @G.Smith No confusion. What you have described is exactly what I meant. The OP is asking about the size of the orbitals that with the spherical symmetry means the radius. The angular distribution is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @safesphere I don’t know what you are trying to say in your second sentence, and I don’t understand how you can look at the plots I provided and think that all orbitals are spherically symmetric. Do you not see that there are 5 upvotes for the comment that “Only $s$ orbitals are symmetric?” After everything I have explained, do you really believe that those 5 people are wrong and your statement was right?

Comment: @safesphere I worry that you think an orbital fits within a sphere of a given radius. It does not. It extends to infinity. The “size” of the infinitely large orbital is measured by the *expectation value* of the radial coordinate of the electron given the probability distribution for finding it anywhere. The size is not measured by the radius of the spheres you showed. Thinking that an atom has an edge is a misconception like thinking that the universe has an edge.

Comment: @G.Smith You got 50 upvotes for a wrong answer the other day, so just 5 mean nothing on this site :) So is the "size" (given by the expectation value) spherically symmetric or does the maximum expectation value depend on the angle? (I mean maximum in the sense of the derivative by the distance to the nucleus.)

Comment: @safesphere For a given wavefunction, the expectation value of $r$ is a number, not a function. As such, it does not have a maximum value. It makes no sense to ask whether this value depends on angle, because it is computed by averaging over all radii and all angles.

Comment: Our discussion is now too long, so I will stop. But I’ll remember it well!

Comment: @G.Smith I see now what you mean by the expectation value. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes perfect sense to define the average radius of any hydrogen orbital $\psi_{nlm}(\vec{r})$,
regardless of whether it is spherically symmetric ($l=0$) or not:

$$ \langle r\rangle = \int r|\psi_{nlm}(\vec{r})|^2 d^3r $$

Evaluating this integral for the hydrogen orbitals $\psi_{nlm}(\vec{r})$
you get (see [FAMU-FSU Col­lege of En­gi­neer­ing - Expectation powers of $r$ for hydrogen](https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/%7Edommelen/quantum/style_a//nt_rsexp.html))
$$ \langle r\rangle = a_0 \frac{3n^2 - l(l+1)}{2}$$
where $a_0$ is the Bohr ra­dius, about 0.53 Å.

Comment: Another criteria can be the maximum extend in a single dimension, a kind of a length, for given arbitrarily chosen probability value defining the surface of the orbital 3D geometrical shape. This has direct applicability for creation molecular orbitals with sp^n hybridization.

Comment: It's interesting that it decreases with $l$ for fixed $n$. The opposite is true for the wavefunctions in nuclear physics. I guess the difference is because the $1/r$ potential is "soft," so by putting some of the KE into radial motion, you can move the classical turning point farther out. In nuclear physics, the potential is more like a hard wall.

Answer (score 2):

You can define $\langle r\rangle$ or $\langle r^2 \rangle$ for different orbitals and compare them. You can check that the average distance of electron form the nucleus is larger for higher orbitals.